#  How to remove unnecessary join, update Where conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got three tables in a MySql database that I'm joining in a query to get id/value pairs.

```
   |    A     |       B      |     C         |
   | -------- |--------------|---------------|
   |   id     |  id          |  id           |
   |   name   |  fooId       |  attributeId  |
   |   desc   |  value       |  displayIndex |
   |   ...    |  attributeId |  ...          |
```

What I have now is:

```
SELECT C.id, B.value
  FROM  A, B, C
  WHERE A.id = B.attributeId
    AND A.id = C.attributeId
    AND B.fooId = 25
  ORDER BY C.displayIndex
```

So basically we're joining B and C through A.  It used to be that an entry in the C table had to have a corresponding (parent) entry in the A table.  However, that will no longer be the case.  The C table will still be MOSTLY controlled by the A table, however, there are some instances when we need a stand alone (always on) entry in the C table.

**EDIT**

I want all the records from B and C that match on attributeId but I also want any record where C.attributeId = -1.  Can someone help with what I'd need to do with this query?

**Edit #2**

Based on feedback and suggestions you guys have made and some googling I now have this:

```
(SELECT C.id, B.value, C.displayIndex
  FROM  B, C
  WHERE B.attributeId = C.attributeId
    AND B.fooId = 25)

UNION

(SELECT C.id, null, C.displayIndex
  FROM C
  WHERE C.attributeId = -1)

ORDER BY 3
```

Is there a better what to do this?  Are there any problems with UNION?

Comment: If there's no A record, will there be a B record with attributeId = -1 (to match the C record) or is fooId=25 the only way to identify the required B record?

Comment: clarify for me....are you looking to just get the b.id,c.value by itself, or are you trying to get these values and the normal a,b,c setup in the same query?  That can be accomplished via a union statement (take Adam's answer and union that to your first statement).  if you don't want the union...right joining to a subquery that gives c.id, b.value will also work.  Not sure if that's what you're asking for though.

Comment: I'm trying to explain the best I can, really sorry if it isn't clear enough.  The UNION idea sounds like it may be what I want.  I want all the records that match on attributeId but I also want any record where C = -1.  This is what I'm calling "Always On".

Comment: One thing I realized already is that table A really doesn't need to be there.  I may be able to remove it from the query all together.

Comment: @MarkBannister There will not be a B record with attributeId = -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated my answer to address the edits from the OP.

This will return all records `where the attributeId for tables B and C match`,
with `B.fooId = 25, OR C.attributeId = -1`.
When `C.attributeId = -1` and there is no match in table B, `NULL` will be returned in place of `B.Value`, which appears to be acceptable based on the `Edit #2` from the OP

```
SELECT C.Id, B.Value, C.displayIndex
FROM C 
LEFT JOIN B ON C.attributeId = B.attributeId
WHERE B.fooId = 25
   OR C.attributeId = -1
ORDER BY C.DisplayIndex ASC
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my OP.  Please see my edits.  This does help but it isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks this does exactly what I want.

Comment: Is there a better title for this question btw?  I feel its way off base just don't know how to word it.

Comment: @kasdega I updated the title, I think it better addresses the question you had.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a Cartesian product.

Like Adam Wenger said you'll need to inner join them. Inner joins will return rows when there is at least 1 match in all joined tables.

If you need to ensure that the result is also in Table A, you're going to need to join that one too:

```
SELECT c.Id, b.Value
FROM B 
INNER JOIN A ON B.attributeId = A.ID
INNER JOIN C ON B.attributeId = C.attributeId
WHERE B.fooId = 25
   AND C.attributeId = -1
ORDER BY C.DisplayIndex
```

Comment: The OP explicitly said "completely ignoring A", since there *won't* be a corresponding Table A record in this case.